# How to burn a video to DVD so it fits

Tags: video, video-editing

I have an m4v video i took while on vacation. It's large (2.3GB) and will fit on a DVD as a file. But i want to burn it in DVD format compatible with most American DVD players. Windows 7 Live Movie Maker says it's too large to fit on the DVD.

[image]

Is there any program i can use so it scales down the quality a bit just enough to fit? Or how would be the best way of doing this?

I have handbreak which i can specify a target size. But i don't know what size that has to be.  As it is now the video is 2.3GB while 4.7GB is the DVD capacity. So i don't know how much more i need to cut down.

Comment: How long is the video? (In terms of time.)

Comment: two hours and 30 minutes 2:29:10.64

Comment: Most commercial DVD's are dual layer because they need more than 1.5 hours of video play time, you will need a dual layer DVD.

Comment: You can only get credit if you post an answer. (+1)